# Reading the MSMQ transactional dead letter queue

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I'm trying to read the transactional deal letter queue in MSMQ using C#.NET and am getting:

> A workgroup installation computer does not support the operation

For 10 Stack Overflow points, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're probably referencing the queue using the wrong kind of FormatName or path. What does yours look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this formatname instead and see if it works:

```
@"FORMATNAME:DIRECT=OS:.\SYSTEM$;DeadXact"
```

Comment: MSDN seems to mention only `MachineName\XactDeadletter$` syntax, which seems to fail in workgroup mode similarly to public queues.